# 'apt-cache policy' reports an older version of youtube-dl as candidate while newer version is installed

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

After updating `youtube-dl` by the command  `youtube-dl -U`, I then proceeded to check the result using `apt-cache policy` and I got the following result:

```
$ apt-cache policy youtube-dl
youtube-dl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2014.02.17-1
  Version table:
     2014.02.17-1 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

The utility's own version reporting gives a different result:

```
$ youtube-dl --version
2020.05.29
```

Two questions:

1. Why is `apt-cache policy` reporting `(none)` after `Installed` even though the application was installed a while ago and was merely updated?
2. Why is `youtube-dl` reporting a more reasonable reply to my `--version` query (date reported is closer to when the `youtube-dl -U` was issued) and what do the dates reported by `apt-cache policy` really signify?

Comment: `which youtube-dl` please.

Comment: Did you even install it using apt in the first place?

Comment: I installed it via `apt-get` ( a while ago ), the install is not an issue, it's working fine. The discrepancy is intriguing and I'm simply curious.

Comment: No, this is the version from git. `youtube-dl --version
2020.05.29`

Comment: Oh it is trusty you use. this release is dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look like your `youtube-dl` is maintained by `apt`, for two reasons:

- As you see, `apt policy` outputs `Installed: (none)`.
- You said that you updated `youtube-dl` using `youtube-dl -U`, but youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Ubuntu, since `apt` maintains the installed version itself when you install the application via `apt`. If you install `youtube-dl` via `apt` and then attempt to run `youtube-dl -U`, you will get an error message that tells you so.

Since you said that you originally installed it using `apt-get`, I could only speculate as to why this would be the case. Perhaps at some point you uninstalled the version from the repos and installed one manually, and forgot about that? Who knows.

Also, the reason why `apt policy` reports `2014.02.17-1` is because that's the latest version available on Trusty (the Ubuntu version you're using). It's the version you *would* get if you installed `youtube-dl` via `apt`. It's not the one that *is* installed; from `apt`'s point of view, this package is not installed.

PS. I would also suggest that you install an up-to-date Ubuntu version. Trusty has reached its end of life over a year ago (and your question is about to be closed for this reason). There will be no more updates (to `youtube-dl` or otherwise), and there haven't been any updates in a year. Hence, you really can't install any up-to-date software with your outdated Ubuntu version (at least not via `apt`).

Comment: your answer clears up my misconceptions, exactly what I was hoping for by asking the question ( Thank You ). As for your recommendation of updating the installation, I'm stuck with this version for now ( for various technical reasons ). Despite resulting form an obsolete release ( 14.04 ) the question is not specific to that release only, your answer points to the subtleties of 'self-updating' apps versus and how `apt` could get left out in the dark. This could happen on any release. Hope your answer will help others with a similar query.